# Which server GGTS used for running?

Tags: tomcat, grails

GGTS having **VMWare vFabric TcServer**. But it didn't use this as default server.
By default,GGTS using server like **Tomcat**.How?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the last few lines of [run-app](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Command%20Line/run-app.html) docs. The default container for Grails is Tomcat.

Comment: Ok.That Tomcat come from where and how?Is it add dynamically?If i want to change the configuration of tomcat mean, how can i change ? and where it is located?

Comment: It is added as a plugin to grails. Look for `tomcat` plugin in `BuildConfig.groovy`. If you have looked at the run-app docs, then the last lines mentions how to uninstall plugin tomcat and use a different server (for example: jetty).

Comment: Using tomcat plugin, tomcat get install.right?If we install some software mean it have location on the disk.Where tomcat is located?where i can see wepapp,bin and conf folder for tomcat.And inside the Vmware fabric tc server having two tomcat.What is the purpose of that two?